# css callback function failed to set width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('.modal-dialog').css({
   'width': function () {
    return ($('.item').width());
    }
    });
```

item is my modal's content, I want to set the dialog size equal to the width of my item, because my items has dynamic size but why above code doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just do as follows:

```
$('.modal-dialog').css({
   'width': $('.item').width();
    });
```

I don't see the necessity to craft the code as you did.

Comment: u have to remove the ; behind the width()

Comment: pls remove the ; behind pls